# visual basic gmail submission not working

Tags: email, gmail, basic

I have the following piece of code which does not seem to work. The error message is below the code.

```
Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
        smtpserver.Port = 465
        smtpserver.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail")
        mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "Test"
        mail.Body = "testing "
        smtpserver.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("Mail Sent")
```

Here is the error message:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.
The server response was:
5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
w6sm4604909qas.26 - gsmtp
```

What does this mean? Why is this not working?

Comment: given that your code is generally the SMALLEST portion of the email chain, there's no way to answer your "question". Your code could be perfect, but your email is getting tossed into the garbage/spam by some other system down the line.

Comment: What error you get? Add error checking code (read the docs, they *should* say how) to find out. Then add error information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not accept unencrypted and/or unauthenticated email submission. Your code needs to use `STARTTLS` like the error message states, and authenticate before trying to send anything.